# How to gsub across every google doc in drive all at once?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I would like to replace all curly quote characters with the generic `"`

Is there anyway to gsub across all documents in my google drive, all at once, so as to replace all `”` and `“` characters with `"`?

Comment: You want to replace **all `”` and `“` characters with `"`** for all Google Document files in your Google Drive. If my understanding is correct, I think that your goal can be achieved using Drive API and Docs API. At first, the file IDs of all Google Document files are retrieved by the method of files.list of Drive API. As the next step, all `”` and `“` characters are converted with `"` by the batchUpdate method of Docs API. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike that’s current. Your idea sounds like a good plan

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your issue will be resolved by the method, I'm glad.